# javascript, electron, ipc doesn't give error or output

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I'm new to js and electron, i keep getting no outputs or errors when running this code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Main.js
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

ipcMain.on('x', function(event, arg) {
    console.log(arg);
});

// index.html
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipc.send('x', "Hello");
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You should open the DevTools console in your main window; there are most certainly error messages displayed there telling you what's going wrong in your renderer process.

There are at least two issues in your code:

1/ The line

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

should be either:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
```

or:

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

2/ Once correctly defined, use `ipcRenderer`, not `ipc`:

```
ipcRenderer.send('x', "Hello");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesn't give any output.

Comment: I have opened the devTools and it says require is not defined. (in index.html)

Comment: You have to enable node Integration in the browser window,

Comment: Yes i have still didn't work. I ended up cloning [this git repo](https://github.com/gopinav/Electron-Tutorials) and that worked.